# Android ndk-r5 calling std:: functions

Tags: c++, android, stl, box2d, android-ndk

i'm just starting to use the ndk-r5 and i need to import a library that
uses std::numeric_limits, std::sort and a couple of more functions from stl.

i'm not sure is those functions are supported using the stlport and if that is the case, what
configuration should i use for building?
what i read from the docs is that you have to include APP_STL := stlport_static on the Application.mk. thats the only additional thing i'm doing but its not working, i get compilation errors when the compiler is on the mentioned functions.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What do the compilation errors say?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get Box2D compiling on android, by replacing all of the <cheader> includes with <header.h>, and fixing up a few things which crop up:
For

```
std::numeric_limits::infinity()
```

I'm using

```
INFINITY /*as defined in float.h ... MAX_FLT is an alternative which might work*/
```

For

```
std::sort(m_pairBuffer, m_pairBuffer + m_pairCount, b2PairLessThan)
```

I did this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
/*...*/
qsort(m_pairBuffer, m_pairCount, sizeof(b2Pair),b2PairQSORTLessThan);
```

with this function defined above:

```
static int b2PairQSORTLessThan(const void*element1,const void*element2)
{
b2Pair *pair1=(b2Pair*)element1;
b2Pair *pair2=(b2Pair*)element2;

if (pair1->proxyIdA < pair2->proxyIdA)
    return -1;//pair1 goes BEFORE pair2
else if (pair1->proxyIdA > pair2->proxyIdA)
    return 1; // pair1 goes AFTER pair2
else{//if (pair1->proxyIdA == pair2->proxyIdA) 
    if (pair1->proxyIdB < pair2->proxyIdB) 
        return -1;
    else if (pair1->proxyIdB > pair2->proxyIdB)
        return 1;
}

return 0; // they are equal

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possibilities here, you'll need to post your compiler errors for a better assessment.

Things to check:
Are you using anything from `num_get_float.cpp`?

Answer (score 0):

Actually most of the errors i can solve them with a C equivalent (like math functions that were called with the std:: namespace) the only two that are causing me problems are:

(1) numeric_limits is not a member of 'std', in: 
float32 infinity = std::numeric_limits::infinity();

and the same kind of error for 'sort', in:
(2) std::sort(m_pairBuffer, m_pairBuffer + m_pairCount, b2PairLessThan);

i suppose that i can use another functions to replace these two. what standard var can i use for infinity?